# SQL Multiple Insert in 1 Table, then Multiple Insert into Table with Foreign Key

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2019

I have 2 tables, **User** and **UserRole**. UserRole references *ID* of User table.

I want to insert multiple rows at 1 time to both tables. Currently, I use table valued parameters, but I am having a difficult time with the insert statements.

I can easily do this in a for loop, but I read that for loops are not good in SQL.

For example, I create the follow table value parameter for insert:

username

- joe
- nathan

userroles

- joe,admin
- nathan,guest

I am having hard time thinking how I can get UserID after User table insert, and use that UserID as Foreign Key in UserRoles table.

Edit:
I am using SQL Server.

Edit 2:
The ideal end result would be:

### User

1,joe
2,nathan

### UserRole

1,admin
2,guest

Comment: What is the database you use ?

Comment: SQL Server 2019

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if this is what you need? If not I will delete my answer so others can try to help also.

```
CREATE TABLE User_t(identity_column INT IDENTITY(1,1) primary key, name varchar(100));

create table UserRole_t(U_id int, Role varchar(100)
                      CONSTRAINT fk_user
                      FOREIGN KEY (U_id)
                      REFERENCES User_t(identity_column));

insert into User_t(name) values('Joe');
Insert into UserRole_t select SCOPE_IDENTITY(), 'admin';
```

[DEMO](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=33ac76a72fff3cd3d4a419d7b9250c02)